# Pass value from a href inside a modal using php

Tags: php, modal-dialog, href

I have a link like this.

```
<a value-id='1' href='#myModal' class='marker' title='Edit'>LINK</a>
```

Inside the modal i would like to receive the value in php.

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">

            <?php
                //CODE TO PUT THE VALUE INSIDE A VARIABLE
            ?>    

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My question is how to put the value inside the variable ?

Comment: where is value? how to get value and put ? please explain .

Comment: the value is ( value-id='1' ) coming from this link (<a value-id='1' href='#myModal' class='marker' title='Edit'>LINK</a>)

Comment: what do you show php code

Comment: i want to show the value of 'value-id' , in this example the value is 1

Answer (score 0):

You can use .on(shown.bs.modal) of bootstrap as below and get its relatedTarget of event and fetch its text.